# Совершенный и несовершенный вид глаголов

Tags: глаголы, грамотная-речь

Почему нельзя сказать: «Здесь тоже не надо переусердствовать»? (ТНТ, 8.11.2014,  16=10, Stand Up, участник программы) Или можно? Я бы сказала «не надо слишком усердствовать».

Comment: @Тина, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

При "не надо", "не стоит", "не требуется" и в других случаях, выражающих **неимперативный запрет (совет или пожелание чего-то не делать)**, обычно используется несовершенный вид глагола. *Почему так - история сложная и не сразу понятная, "нельзя", например, вполне допускает при себе совершенный вид.*

Но некоторые глаголы, "усердствовать" в их числе, не имеют специальной парадигмы-основы для образования несовершенного вида от приставочных форм. "Переусердствовать" может соответствовать и совершенному, и несовершенному виду. Поэтому исходная фраза не может считать грамматически некорректной. Но вот смысл её настолько размыт, что она воспринимается как ошибочная. С этих позиций ваша правка вполне разумна.

Comment: Вы пишете:«"Переусердствовать" может соответствовать и совершенному, и несовершенному виду.» Т.е. глагол  "Переусердствовать" можно понимать и как глагол несовершенного вида? «Что ты делаешь? – Я переусердствую»? Это грамотный текст?

Answer (score 0):

Можно и без обобщающих правил заметить, в чём недостаток этого выражения. "Не надо" (не стоит) по смыслу - совет "не начинать" указанного действия, а "переусердствовать" (сов. вид) характеризует законченное действие. Поэтому с данным глаголом уместнее сказать "нельзя", и это может косвенно означать: нельзя (своими действиями) допустить, чтобы в результате вышло, что вы переусердствовали.